# git pull returns "not a git repository" error

Tags: git, pull

I am attempting to pull my code from a remote repo. When I run 'git pull' I get the following message:

```
$ git pull
root@gohyperspace.com's password:
fatal: 'var/www/html' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Here's my config settings:

```
$ git config -l
core.symlinks=false
core.autocrlf=true
color.diff=auto
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
color.interactive=true
pack.packsizelimit=2g
help.format=html
http.sslcainfo=/bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt
sendemail.smtpserver=/bin/msmtp.exe
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
rebase.autosquash=true
merge.tool=tortoisemerge
gui.recentrepo=C:/Users/Chris/Dev/Projects/html
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.symlinks=false
core.ignorecase=true
core.hidedotfiles=dotGitOnly
remote.origin.url=root@gohyperspace.com:var/www/html
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
user.name=Chris Barnhill
user.email=*@gmail.com
gui.wmstate=normal
gui.geometry=887x427+26+26 171 192
```

By the way, 'gui.recentrepo' is wrong. My local repo is located in `/Users/Chris/Dev/Projects/Hyperspace/html'`

Comment: try cloning the repo in a new directory. if it doesn't work, something is foobar with the repo.

Answer (score 1):

Are you positive of the remote repo location? Should it be /var/www/html?

It appears that you're accessing the relative path.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering based on your [updated question](https://superuser.com/a/609478/251572). You are trying to push to a non-bare repository, which means a repository that actually contains artifacts. A bare repository is one that "[doesn't contain a working directory](http://git-scm.com/book/ch4-2.html)". In the remote repo, you are trying to push to, the master branch is checked out and so Git rejects the attempt.

To explain a bit further, imagine Alice, and Bob are working on the same project. Bob clones Alice's working repository, then they both went separate ways, but work on the same branch, say `master`. If Bob tries to push his changes to `origin/master`, which is Alice's working repository, *and* Git allows it, Alice would suddenly be working with a new state of the code base she isn't aware of (and might not want). This is just one sample scenario.